# NSNumberFormatter Currency Without Symbol?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, currency, nsnumberformatter

I am using NSNumberFormatter to get a currency value from a string and it works well.

I use this code to do so:

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSString *price = [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[textField.text floatValue]]];
```

However, it always gives me a currency symbol at the start of the string. Rather than doing it manually form my given string, can I not somehow have the formatter not give the string any currency symbol?

Comment: Mind that it won't always be at the start - for Euro prices you will have something like 12,34€

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, after you set the style, you can tweak specific aspects:

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[nf setCurrencySymbol:@""]; // <-- this
NSDecimalNumber* number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[textField text]];
NSString *price = [nf stringFromNumber:number];
```

Just as some advice, you should probably use a number formatter to read the string value, especially if a user is entering it (as suggested by your code). In this case, if the user enters locale-specific formatting text, the generic `-floatValue` and `-doubleValue` type methods won't give you truncated numbers. Also, you should probably use `-doubleValue` to convert to a floating point number from user-entered text that's a currency. There's more information about this in the WWDC'12 developer session video on internationalization.

*Edit: Used an `NSDecimalNumber` in the example code to represent the number the user enters. It's still not doing proper validation, but better than the original code. Thanks [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151019/mark)!*

Comment: For money you might well want to use NSDecimalNumber rather than double so that you do not have rounding issues

Comment: @Mark Yeah, I agree, I'm actually going to edit the original code to do that.

Answer (score 10):

With Swift 5, `NumberFormatter` has a property called [`currencySymbol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1414668-currencysymbol). `currencySymbol` has the following declaration:

```
var currencySymbol: String! { get set }
```

> The string used by the receiver as a local currency symbol.

Therefore, if required for your formatting style, you can set this property to an empty `String`.

---

The following Playground sample code shows how to set your currency formatting style with an empty symbol:

```
import Foundation

let amount = 12000

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
formatter.currencySymbol = ""
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US") // set only if necessary

let result = formatter.string(for: amount)
print(String(describing: result)) // prints: Optional("12,000.00")
```

Answer (score 2):

as for Swift Language

```
let mymoney = 12000

let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
formatter.currencySymbol = ""
formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

let resultString = formatter.stringFromNumber(mymoney)!
```

Answer (score 2):

Displays 9,999.99 without the currency & not as Optional.

```
let myDouble = 9999.99
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
currencyFormatter.currencySymbol = ""
// localize to your grouping and decimal separator
currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.current

// We'll force unwrap with the !, if you've got defined data you may need more error checking

let priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: myDouble))!
print(priceString) // Displays 9,999.99 without the currency & not as Optional
```