# Swift NSNumberFormatter CurrencyStyle Without Symbol

Tags: swift, currency, nsnumberformatter

This question has been answered in objective-c [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522436/nsnumberformatter-currency-without-symbol). How can I do it in Swift?

Comment: How about you post your actual question here?

Comment: How can i accept them as answers? Some of them are very good

Comment: You can only accept one answer to your own question as correct. For other questions, you can only upvote a helpful answer by using the arrows next to the answer.

Comment: Don't see any accept button on the page.  Should I click on the answer, then it will show up ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jwu494cg3r92vcu/file%20may%2031%2C%204%2056%2025%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: If you're going to use APIs that were created in C and Objective-C in a language that is still not stably defines you will do better to learn it in those languages as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import UIKit

let nf = NumberFormatter()
nf.currencySymbol = ""
nf.numberStyle = .currency
let stringForNumber = nf.string(for: 100)  // "100.00"
```

Comment: nf.currencySymbol = ""  
get Expected declaration.

Comment: it is being imported already. and  Vote Up requires 15 reputation for me.

Comment: if it is iOS you have to import UIKit. The code above should be fine

Comment: The error message pops up in xcode Version 6.3.1 (6D1002). @Leo Dabus